# change the background color of answers on a quiz app

Tags: android

sorry for my ignorance. I implemented this quiz activity so that once the user has decided on the answer, he presses and the btn backround becomes light blue and then he has to press next to go to the next question. However, I would like that once the answer is pressed the application colors its green if it's correct. if not, color it red and color the right answer green. then he must press next to move to the next question. here is my QuizActivity.kt code

```
companion object {
        var questionModelList : List<QuestionModel> = listOf()
        var time : String = ""
    }
    lateinit var binding: ActivityQuizBinding

    var currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    var selectedAnswer = ""
    var score = 0;


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding= ActivityQuizBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.apply {
            btn0.setOnClickListener(this@QuizActivity)
            btn1.setOnClickListener(this@QuizActivity)
            btn2.setOnClickListener(this@QuizActivity)
            nextBtn.setOnClickListener(this@QuizActivity)
        }
        loadQuestion()
        startTimer()
    }

    private fun startTimer(){
        val totalTimeInMillis = time.toInt() * 60 * 1000;
        object  : CountDownTimer(totalTimeInMillis.toLong(),1000L){
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                val seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000
                val minutes = seconds / 60
                val remainingSeconds = seconds % 60
                binding.timerIndicatorTextview.text = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes,remainingSeconds)
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                //finish the quiz
            }

        }.start()
    }

    private fun loadQuestion(){
        selectedAnswer = ""
        if(currentQuestionIndex == questionModelList.size){
            finishQuiz()
            return
        }

        binding.apply {
            questionIndicatorTextview.text = "Question ${currentQuestionIndex+1}/ ${questionModelList.size} "
            questionProgressIndicator.progress =
                (currentQuestionIndex.toFloat() / questionModelList.size.toFloat() * 100).toInt()
            questionTextview.text = questionModelList[currentQuestionIndex].question
            btn0.text = questionModelList[currentQuestionIndex].options[0]
            btn1.text = questionModelList[currentQuestionIndex].options[1]
            btn2.text = questionModelList[currentQuestionIndex].options[2]


        }
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {

        binding.apply {
            btn0.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.gray))
            btn1.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.gray))
            btn2.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.gray))
        }

        val clickBtn = view as Button
        if(clickBtn.id ==R.id.next_btn){
            //next button is clicked
            if(selectedAnswer == questionModelList[currentQuestionIndex].correct){
                score++;
                Log.i("score of quiz",score.toString())
            }
            currentQuestionIndex++
            loadQuestion()
        }else{
            selectedAnswer = clickBtn.text.toString()
            clickBtn.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.lightblue))
        }
    }
    private fun finishQuiz(){
        val totalQuestions = questionModelList.size
        val percentage = (score.toFloat() / totalQuestions.toFloat() * 100).toInt()

        val dialogBinding = ScoreDialogBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        dialogBinding
        dialogBinding.apply {
            scoreProgressIndicator.progress = percentage
            scoreProgressText.text = "$percentage %"
            if(percentage>60){
                scoreTitle.text = "Congrats! You have passed"
                scoreTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
                }
            else{
                scoreTitle.text = "Oops! You have failed"
                scoreTitle.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            }
            scoreSubtitle.text = "$score out of $totalQuestions are correct"
            finishBtn.setOnClickListener({
                finish()
            })
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(dialogBinding.root)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .show()
    }
```

i tried to use chatgpt but i'm not good